# Cross domain anchor links within an iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain

I have  two test case scenarios. I am loading an iFrame within the same domain and the same iFrame in another domain. Within the same domain, the simple anchor tags go to the appropriate position, but within the different domain, the anchor links refuse to work. I am guessing it is a cross domain issue, but why would the anchor tags refuse to take you to the appropriate place within the iFrame? I don't see how that would be a security risk. Anyway below are the two urls. You will see the navigation for the iframe on the right hand side. On the same domain it works, but on the other domain it refuses to do so.

[Same Domain](http://fnbsocialmedia.co.za/fnbblog/?page_id=574) and [Cross Domain](http://www.youcanhelp.co.za/vote-to-help/). Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Pages are big. Where I should click?

Comment: There is a "video-playlist" that scrolls you to the correct video. Were you able to find it?

Comment: Yes. Now I see what's the problem, but can't say what is caused. Basically, anchor have target = "_self" by default, so iframe source should changes with #anchorname appended. But it does not happens. Are you sure you don't bind some js event handlers to anchors? I asking because your "cross-domain" page actually works in Opera, but failes in Chrome.

Comment: Very interesting. Let me double check on different browsers. Theatrically should this not be a problem cross-domain? Just curious before I start digging into the codebase to see if there could be any js from the parent interfering with the iframe. Thanks for the help Tommy.